# Using project in project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Windows Phone 7 provides a map-control, but it has not all features, I would like to use in my app. E.g. navigation service has to be implemented. Therefore there are some tutorials, like here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wp7trainingcourse_usingbingmapslab_topic2

There is a lot of work to do, before one has an app with navigation, and even than not all implementation of tutorial works like desired. Therefore MS provides a project with "end-solution".  I saw, that Visual Studio generates a .dll file of a project.

I would like to use a project with Bing maps navigation from MS tutorial in my Project.
I could add a dll as a reference from bing maps project, but how can I use it? E.g. I have my MainPage.xaml in a new project, and I would like to show directly the mainpage.xaml-screen of the dll.

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulties with?

Comment: 1. Is it really possible to add a projects dll to another project to run "app-in-app"
2. how can I make this app-in-app visible? I create an object of  "importedprojectsname".App   and then?

Comment: If the `dll` is a .NET assembly, you can simply add it. You can then call any public methods defined on the objects in this assembly. This is no different from any other .NET assembly, including the ones supplied by Microsoft in the BCL.

Comment: @Oded: assuming, of course, that it was built targeting the Phone.

Comment: @Oded I know how to use public methods of dlls. My Question was: how to make an App visible if I import it as dll.

Comment: If it's a DLL it is not an executable. I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Since all the source files are available in the above mentioned training kit under: "Source\Ex1-TheBingMapControl\End" , you should definitely work from those files.

In that case there won't be any DLL problem you encounter.

Source files can be downloaded for this training kit here: http://az12722.vo.msecnd.net/wp7trainingcourse1-4/labs/usingbingmapslab1-1-0/Source.zip

Comment: I thought about it also. but it would be much better for me if I do it as I described :)